# Detect iPhone / iPod / iPad Capacity

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am creating an application which needs to detect the make and model of the device it is running on (including hard disk size).  I have found plenty of post's on how to identify different iPhone model's but can't find any reference to detecting the HD size.

Is this even possible?

Thanks in advance,
Oli

Comment: I doubt this is possible.  Apple doesn't want programs to know anything about the device itself, or how to access areas on the Drive outside of the App's sandbox.

Comment: You'd think so, Stephen, but I read recently that the basic Unix functions documented in the form of man pages are allowed. Seems like an oversight to me.

Comment: Anything with a header file in the iOS SDK is probably fair game. Note that there are two "disk" devices; one is (more or less) the firmware image, the other is the user data partition.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, in the end I went for the approach I have posted in the answers.

Comment: That's probably the right thing to do in this case anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit more digging I went for the following approach as it seemed the most straight forward and seems to work fine.

Thanks to BastiBense for your solution and and I will look into POSIX further in the future.

```
NSDictionary *fsAttr = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfFileSystemForPath:NSHomeDirectory() error:nil];
float diskSize = [[fsAttr objectForKey:NSFileSystemSize] doubleValue] / 1000000000;
NSLog(@"Disk Size: %0.0f",diskSize);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think default POSIX things should be available on iOS.

You might want to take a look at `statvfs` (part of the standard C library) and use that to read the amount of free disk space. It's not part of the Cocoa API, but that makes sense.

Documentation should be on your machine. In Terminal do: `man statvfs`.

Hope that helps. Should be a 5-liner to get the information you need. :)

Answer (score 1):

The POSIX version (bit of a hack):

```
#include <sys/statvfs.h>

double get_disk_capacity ( char * path)
{
    struct statvfs sfs;
    unsigned long long result = 0;
    double disk_capacity = 0;

    if ( statvfs ( path, &sfs) != -1 )
    {
        result = (unsigned long long)sfs.f_frsize * sfs.f_blocks;

        if (result > 0)
        {
            disk_capacity = (double)result/(1024*1024);
        }
    }

    return disk_capacity;
}

// Sum the size of the two logical partitions (root + user space)
double total_capacity = get_disk_capacity("/") + get_disk_capacity("/private/var");

printf( "%.2f MB", total_capacity);
```